# Using the text box and radio buttons to search for items in the database.

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to figure out how to use the text box and radio buttons to search for items in the database. Here's my code so far. I'm a php beginner. Also I'm kinda confused btw pdo and mysqli. I'm really stuck. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>northwind database</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//connect databse
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=northwind';

$username ='sa' ;//'mgs_user';
$password = '123';//'pa55word';

try {
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  echo'<p>You are connected</p>';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  include('database_error.php');
  exit();

  require_once ('index.php');
}
?>
<?php
//PDO:: query
/*function getFruit($conn) {
  $sql = 'SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers ORDER BY first_name';
  foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['id'] . "\t";
    print $row['first_name'] . "\t";
    print $row['last_name'] . "\n";
  }
}*/


$query="SELECT id,Company, first_name, last_name FROM customers";
$display = $db->prepare($query);
$display->execute();
$customer = $display->fetchAll();
$display->closeCursor();



?>




<h1> Customer List </h1>

    <p>Search</p>
    <form name="searchDatabase" method="post" action="Index,php">
      <input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50" /><br />
      <input name="RadioId" type="radio" value="Id" />ID<br />
      <input name="RadioId" type="radio" value="Company" />Company<br />
      <input name="RadioId" type="radio" value="FName" />First Name<br />
      <input name="RadioId" type="radio" value="LName" />Last Name<br />
      <input name="RadioId" type="radio" value="Title" />Title<br />
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" size="10" value="Search" />

    </form>
<br /><br />


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>


<?php foreach ($customer as $cus) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $cus['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $cus['Company']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $cus['first_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $cus['last_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
</body>
```